# How can I calculate this integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, numerical-methods

How can I numerically calculate the integral below from the following values?

E : complex electric field vector at each point
H : complex magnetic field vector at each point
x : coordinate along x axis
y : coordinate along y axis
(These values are obtained from a finite-difference eigenmode solver)

$$
\iint_S \vec{E} \times \vec{H}^* \cdot \vec{dS}\\
$$

[Computational window of the solver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhhCT.jpg)

Comment: You could use a 2-D simpson's rule approach to numerically integrate, you'd have to divide up your region into squares and evaluate the integrand numerically, etc.   There might be perl or python packages out there which you can use, or write your own.

Comment: >> user247608 Thank you I will try what you suggested.